Monetdb recovery from crash and backup
We are using Monetdb as our BI database. Sometimes we experience crash of the database during some query execution.
The data is critical and database needs to recover, but there is no way how to recover form the crash.
Is there any way we recover from the crashed db without any loss of the data or a very minimal loss(in this case we can rerun the process to insert data again).
There is a way to backup the database as explained here - ([Backup][1]https://www.monetdb.org/documentation-Dec2023/admin-guide/backup-upgrade/hot-backup/
But the backup utility can still loose the data in case of crash before the backup is done.
Please guide on the strategy.

Seems you've encountered multiple problems.  It's best to report each problem separately to the MonetDB team (https://github.com/monetdb/monetdb/issues) with detailed description of the problem.  If possible, provide query, sample data, scripts, etc to reproduce the problem.
